# The number of sample size in this case

Tags: anova, p-value, sample-size, kruskal-wallis-test

I'm trying to compare three conditions (A, B, C). And I have a question about the sample size in this experiment.
There were 27 participants, and each participant listened to 20 songs for each condition. (I have counter-balanced the order, and 20 songs were the same for everyone.)

So the number of the result for surveys goes like this (Px = Participant number X) ...

**P1**
A: 20
B: 20
C: 20

**P2**
A: 20
B: 20
C: 20

.
.
.

**P27**
A: 20
B: 20
C: 20

Every participants have done Likert scale for each music, so the total number of surveys are 1620 (27 people X 3 conditions X 20 music). And each condition has 540 surveys. (27 people X 20 music).

**In this case, should I count my sample size as 27(participant number), or 540(participant number X number of songs)?**

Answer (score 0):

In standard formulae that apply to this case, there should be separate notation for participants, conditions, items (not necessarily called like this), so you should know what is what. What you *call* sample size is secondary if you use the formulae correctly.

I'd call 27 "sample size" here and 540 maybe "number of records", but note that this may depend on what exactly I'm communicating to whom. In mathematics terms are what they are defined to be, and different people may use different definitions. If there is no explicit definition, they are at least potentially unclear, and if terms are ambiguous, better use them with an exact description what they are.

Comment: Then in order to compare its means, should I use average of 27 people's data?

Comment: @user372833 If you want help with analysing your data, you better open another question.